# three.js leaks pixels from the videocard when rendering a png with alpha channel

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I had a hard time figuring a proper title for this question..
I am loading PNG files from external URL, but with one particular PNG, no-power-of-two, alpha-chanel, created with gimp, when I loaded and use as texture in a plane, It renders mixed with what it looks like screenshots portions of the current screen. in the attached screenshot you will see that it looks like if the cat had a layer on top with inverted parts of the chromium developer inspector window, that is opened at the right.
I notice that it says that as the image is not power of two, has to be resized, but I had not noticed that behavior with other textures.
[image]
using three.js R77, Chromium Version 57.0.2987.98 Built on Ubuntu , running on Ubuntu 16.04 (64-bit)

Answer (score 2):

Yikes, that's a bug in the browser. Could you please post a self-contained sample showing the problem? If it's not too much trouble please create a bug on crbug.com/ and attach it, but otherwise please just put the test case somewhere and send me a link. Thanks. (I work on Chrome's WebGL implementation.)